# python reading wrong type

Tags: python, python-2.7, types

I have a text file that contains lines of numbers. My program is trying to extract the lines of code and put them in a list, with each list being composed of the numbers that make up that line in the file, and then put all of these lists into one list *(lets call this Triangle)* and have a function applied to them, but the Python interpreter says that `Triangle[x]` is an integer type when I am trying to work with it, but when I ask it `type(Triangle[x]`), it says that it is a list.  My code is below:

```
def compare(a,b):
"""Returns the larger of a and b"""
if a > b:
    return a
else:
    return b

doc = open('C:/Users/Joseph/My Documents/Programming fun/Python/Project Euler/18triangle.txt')

Triangle = []

for line in doc:
    Triangle.append( map( int, line.split() ) )

doc.close()

Triangle.reverse()

for i in xrange(len(Triangle) - 1):
    for j in xrange(len(Triangle[i]) - 1):              # Here it says that 'type int has no len'
        TEMP = compare(Triangle[i][j],Triangle[i][j + 1])
        Triangle[i+1] = TEMP
```

Thank you in advance for any advice you can offer.

Comment: What do you expect `map(int, line.split())` to do exactly? Is int() a function?

Comment: It is a function, yes. That's a fairly not-uncommon line to see.

Comment: Integers don't have a `length` attribute.  They are integers.

Comment: line.split() returns all of the numbers as a list, but since they were in a text file, they were strings. I mapped the int() function onto all of the numbers, which converts the string '57' into the integer 57, for example

Comment: Is your compare() function the same as the max() function?

Answer (score 4):

This looks suspicious:

```
TEMP = compare(Triangle[i][j],Triangle[i][j + 1])
Triangle[i+1] = TEMP
```

`Triangle` starts out with lists of integers as members, but as you go through you're assigning elements to be integers. In fact, this happens for each element other than `Triangle[0]`, so this will always happen as soon as `i` gets to `1`.

---

By the way, this is a somewhat nicer way to read the document:

```
with open('C:/Users/Joseph/My Documents/Programming fun/Python/Project Euler/18triangle.txt') as doc:
    Triangle = [map(int, line.split()) for line in doc]
```

And your `compare` function is a subset of the standard `max` function; you could just use that instead (as pointed out by @BrendenBrown in the comments).

Also, `Triangle` should be `triangle` according to [standard Python style](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Ah! ok, then I just need to add another index so it will be Triangle[i+1][j] = TEMP.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that TEMP gets an integer, and then you put that into Triangle, so now Triangle has an element that is an integer rather than a list. Maybe you want something like

```
Triangle[i+1] = [TEMP]
```

instead of

```
Triangle[i+1] = TEMP
```

Answer (score 1):

`for i in xrange(len(Triangle) - 1)` this is not very pythonic.

Since you want to compare two objects at once, first adjusting the list might be better. This snippet converts your list into a list of 2-tuples

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest, islice
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> list(izip_longest(islice(x,0,None,2),islice(x,1,None,2)))
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, None)]
```

Once you have the list in that format, you can step through it like this:

```
for i,j in two_list:
   # rest of your loop
```